# What is the best approach to make Data Receive / Data Listener keeps alive?

Tags: c#, async-await, tcp

I have task to create a client application for data communication via TCP and I have no experience in TCP data communication programming. I use C# and VS2013. In the company I work at there is a black-boxed server application. I only know its ip, port and its behaviors on data communication:

1. it is waiting for XML-formatted and UTF8 encoded message. Other format or encoding will be ignored.
2. as soon as it gets the message, it sends the received message as acknowledgement back.
3. the server can also send another message to client without receiving message from client first.

I have implemented the point 1 and 2 (see my code below), they work. But I am confused (at point 3) **how to make the "waiting and receive data" part into a loop that keeps alive till the client application is closed.** Thanks in advance for any help and hints.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleTest01
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const String _xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
        private const String _xmlEndTag = "</xml>";
        private static TcpClient _client;
        private static NetworkStream _stream;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Connect("127.0.0.1", 4502, "<DummySettings></DummySettings>");
        }

        static void Connect(String server, Int32 port, String message)
        {
            try
            {
                _client = new TcpClient(server, port);

                // Prepare data
                message = _xmlHeader + message + _xmlEndTag;
                Byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                Byte[] suffix = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n");
                Byte[] utf8Result = new byte[data.Length + suffix.Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, utf8Result, 0, data.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(suffix, 0, utf8Result, data.Length,      suffix.Length);

                // Send data
                if (_client != null) _stream = _client.GetStream();
                _stream.Write(utf8Result, 0, utf8Result.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

                // Waiting and receive data
                var acknowledgement = new Byte[data.Length + suffix.Length];
                String responseData = String.Empty;
                Int32 bytes = _stream.Read(acknowledgement, 0,     acknowledgement.Length);
                responseData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(acknowledgement, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

                // In real life the close commands are not called here.
                _stream.Close();
                _client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** more information about my code.

With my code above I can send message to server **and** get server's acknowledgement, then the application is closed per design since it is only my experiment code. User Prabhu understands my case correctly.

Now I want to know how to implement the receive-only part to handle the case if the server sends another message to my client and my client can process the message. Therefore the receive-part should keep alive to listen incoming message till my client application is closed. It probably involves background threading (where I have no experience with). An example code (or link to it) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: it's kindof hard for us to explain your requirements if you are yourself unsure - but my best guess would be that you should open a connection to the client on demand for 3 (not keep those from 1/2 alive)

Comment: The most important question to ask is whether Send/Receive can happen at the same time. If so, then on the client side there must be two threads using different socket each.

Comment: @matcheek the send and receive can not happen at the same time. But using different socket and thread is a good idea. It needs probably a async background thread waiting for incoming data from server? I have no experience for background threading. Any example?

Comment: @Carsten the send-and-receive-acknowledgement part is ok. I just don't know how to implement the receive-only part. The receive-only part should keep alive while the client application runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find a solution of the problem. I am not sure if it is a best practice or not, but it works in my case. If someone has better idea to improve my solution, please let me know.

The background worker:

```
    private static void StartListening()
    {
        _dataLength = (_dataLength < (32 * 1024)) ? 32 * 1024 : _dataLength;

        while (!_shouldStop) // _shouldStop is a boolean private field
        {
            try
            {
                if (_stream.DataAvailable) // _stream is a NetworkStream
                {
                    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[_dataLength];
                    Int32 readBytes = _stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    // ResponseData is a property of type String
                    ResponseData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioex)
            {
                // Do nothing since the client and socket are already closed.
            }
        }
    }
```

And the caller:

```
    _shouldStop = false;
    var t = new Thread(MyClass.StartListening);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap a loop around the send-receive pair:

```
while (true) {
 var data = ...;
 Send(data);
 var receivedData = Receive();
 Debug.Assert(data == receivedData);
}
```

Like that.

Since there are no two operations happening at the same time it is not necessary to use async IO or threads. I would especially advise against non-blocking sockets and the "select" method because that is outdated on .NET 4.5 with await.

Your current code is broken because it assumes that read operations will return a specific number of bytes. This is not so, see the docs.

Use `BinaryReader` to easily read an exact number of bytes.

Comment: Thx. But I think you misunderstood the case. I have revised the case.

Comment: Well, I need probably something non-blocking. I use .NET 4.5. I will take a look about await.

Comment: So you can have two reads at the same time? An acknowledgement read and a read for other data? That's quite hard. You should probably rethink this problem and find something simpler. For example, why are you using sockets at all. Can't you use WCF to exchange messages/calls? Or HTTP. I could pull this off but I never would choose to do so.

Comment: About WCF, do both server and client need to use WCF? The server I talk about is black-boxed and written using C++ and uses no WCF for sure, and I have no its code and can't change the code. If it is doesn't matter, whether the server uses WCF or not, I will try to use WCF for the client. My SO doesn't want to use HTTP.

Comment: If the server is a black box then you can't use WCF or HTTP because you can't change the wire protocol. You're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You application requirements calls for non-blocking sockets. As events can happen asynchronosly.

1. Send data to server
2. Receive response from server for sent data and process
3. Receive server's own message and process.

You can have one dedicated thread which monitors on the connected socket b/w the client and server. You can use `select` mechanism for monitoring. Call it socket-thread. The thread which sends data to server - call it worker thread.

The connected socket id `sd` shall be shared b/w the threads. As and when the worker thread has data to send to server, it shall do `send` on the connected `sd`. The response from the server should wake up the socket-thread polling on `sd`. It should fully receive the message (application should take care of identifying the complete message) and pass on the data to worker thread for processing.

Similary, socket-thread will be woken up when the server message(non-response) comes in. The same shall be passed on to worker thread.

The worker thread can be in a event loop to do things listed above.

Comment: Very good explained! do you have any example code (or link to it) for background threading? I still have no experience with background threading. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MagB, I am not versed with C#. So not able to help you in terms of code. Conceptually had an inderstanding of your needs hence commented with how one can do the implementation.